# Javascript search JSON for name return parent object

Tags: javascript, json

Using this JSON object I am trying to find the parent object of xpublisher:

```
{
 type: "object",
 title: "Scalars",
 properties: {
   stringProperty: {
     description: "Property name's description (type is string)",
     type: "string",
     examples: [
       "example",
       "sample",
     ],
     xpublisher: [
       "Greg",
       "Tom",
     ],
   },
   writeOnlyStringProperty: {
     description: "Notice this only appears in the request.",
     xpublisher: [
       "John",
       "Anna",
     ],
     type: "string",
     writeOnly: true,
     examples: [
       "example",
     ],
   },
   minLengthString: {
     xpublisher: [
       "Nancy",
       "Tim",
     ],
     description: "Property name's description (type is string)",
     type: "string",
     minLength: 4,
     examples: [
       "example",
     ],
   },
 },
 }
```

I would like to search for xpublisher and return the parent object that includes the xpublisher tag so the first one found would be:

```
stringProperty: {
    description: "Property name's description (type is string)",
    type: "string",
    examples: [
      "example",
      "sample",
    ],
    xpublisher: [
      "Greg",
      "Tom",
    ],
  },
```

I have tried a few different way including:

```
   function getPublishers(obj, name) {
      let result = [];
      for (var key in obj) {
          let keyName = obj[key]
          console.log(keyName)
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if ("object" == typeof(obj[key])) {
                  getPublishers(obj[key], name);
              } else if (key == name) {
                  result.push(obj[key]);
              }
          }
      }
      return result;
  }
```

And I also tried to find the key name this way also.

```
function searchObject(obj, name) {
   let result = Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k][name]);
   return result;
}
```

The code seems to only find key numbers not actually the key names so I can then grab the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function traverse(object: Object, propertyKey: string) {
    if(propertyKey in object) return object;
    const keys = Object.keys(object);
     
    for(const key of keys) {
         if(typeof object[key] === "object" && !Array.isArray(object[key])) {
            const result = traverse(object[key], propertyKey);
            if(result !== null) return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find by checking the object and the values.

```js
const
    findParent = (object, key) => {
        if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;
        if (key in object) return object;
        for (const o of Object.values(object)) {
            const p = findParent(o, key);
            if (p) return p;
        }
    },
    data = { type: "object", title: "Scalars", properties: { stringProperty: { description: "Property name's description (type is string)", type: "string", examples: ["example", "sample"], xpublisher: ["Greg", "Tom"] }, writeOnlyStringProperty: { description: "Notice this only appears in the request.", xpublisher: ["John", "Anna"], type: "string", writeOnly: true, examples: ["example"] }, minLengthString: { xpublisher: ["Nancy", "Tim"], description: "Property name's description (type is string)", type: "string", minLength: 4, examples: ["example"] } } };

console.log(findParent(data, 'xpublisher'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```